# How to implement std::is_nothrow_constructible

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

So recently I was trying out some template metaprogramming after watching some cppcon talks, and I was trying to re-implement some of the traits in type-traits, but I got to `std::is_nothrow_constructible` and I got stuck. I was wondering how this could be implemented. Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to re-implement [std::is_constructible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)?

Comment: Here's the libc++ implementation: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/fafc6e4fdf3673dcf557d6c8ae0c0a4bb3184402/libcxx/include/type_traits#L3068-L3113

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, I could do that

Comment: @jtbandes I tried that implementation with `is_nothrow_constructible<int, int>` and it returns false, when it should be true

Comment: I just copied the libc++ implementation verbatim with a few changes to fix it up, and `is_nothrow_constructible<int, int>` returns true: https://godbolt.org/z/4P25Yb